# How to get Device log in iOS simulator using bash cmd

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, bash

im new in bash... how to get the simulator device log using bash i try to use this tail -f ~/Library/Logs/iOS\ Simulator//system.log but it didnt work am i missing something

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works for me:

```
tail -f ~/Library/Logs/iOS\ Simulator/7.1/system.log
```

Note the "7.1" subdirectory.